# How to get 3D effect of div like a putter?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to achieve the 3D effect on a `div` like a putter has. I have included the image and marked the area for the shape I am looking for. Kindly guide me how I can do this. Thanks.

[image]

I have placed 3 `div`s here to get the effect of black and green, but the shape of the `div` must be like a putter.

Here is my HTML

```
<div class="puttercolordiv" id="about">
                        <span class="paint-area">&nbsp;</span>
                        <span class="paint-area">&nbsp;</span>
                        <span class="paint-area">&nbsp;</span>
                    </div>
```

People who make my question not reasonable then kindly provide the answer as well, i not need radius effect only, i need that curve effect as well.

[image]

Comment: Consider google; perhaps search for "3d effect on div".

Comment: 3d effect means like this putter curve at the end, i just want my div curve and give that effect. So far i try i with radius but it did not work

Comment: @DwB i try but not find this kind of effect.

Comment: Radius is the way to go.

Comment: Don't forget to add your HTML and CSS code.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/43oew4h4/4/

```css
#rounded {
  width: 250px;
  height: 500px;
  border-radius: 15% 50% 50% 15%;
  -moz-border-radius: 15% 50% 50% 15%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 15% 50% 50% 15%;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: silver;
}

#inner {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  background: black;
}

#inner2 {
  background: green;
  width: 100%;
  height: 160px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 70px;
}

#inner3 {
  background: black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 60px;
}

#rim {
  position: absolute;
  width: 90%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 15% 50% 50% 15%;
  -moz-border-radius: 15% 50% 50% 15%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 15% 50% 50% 15%;
  /* Permalink - use to edit and share this gradient: http://colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#ffffff+0,ffffff+100&0+0,1+100 */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, transparent 50%, rgba(255,255,255,0.7) 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, transparent 50%,rgba(255,255,255,0.7) 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(to right, transparent 50%,rgba(255,255,255,0.7) 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
}
```

```html
<div id="rounded">
  <div id="inner">
    <div id="inner2">
      <div id="inner3">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="rim">
  </div>
</div>
```

Next time please include what you have tried so far in your question.

Comment: but it not provide curve effect

Comment: Could you elaborate?

Comment: I think the OP want's a 3d effect - http://jsfiddle.net/43oew4h4/1/ just add some shadowing

Comment: @HubertGrzeskowiak i upload the image above you can check it

Comment: Answer updated to resemble the light rim and the rectangles inside the paddle.

Comment: @HubertGrzeskowiak Thanks for this

Comment: You're welcome. Don't forget to accept the answer if you go with this. By the way, next time you try something this complex, consider using SVG.

Answer (score 0):

`Border-radius` is the way to go - you were on the right track:

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #aaa;
  border-radius: 0 50% 50% 0;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: it not provide that curve effect like putter have, i need that one, not only radius.

Comment: You can play with gradients, but making it look like that image would be very tough.

Comment: i try many things to get that effect, example i try a shaded image over there to get that one but it not work.